# Use appropriate colors irrespective of themes

Tags: android, colors, themes

I want my activity to have two possible themes, say `Theme_Holo` and `Theme_Holo_Light`, as selected by the user. I need to programmatically draw things like horizontal dividers in this activity. The color of the divider should depend on the selected theme. How can I do that easily?

Ideally there should be a name for the standard color of a divider irrespective of the theme used, and the actual RGB realization of that color name would match the selected theme automatically. Is there such thing? It seems unlikely to me that the programmer needs to hardcode RBG values.

Of course, the divider is only an example. I would also like to name the color of EditText, or other widgets, in a way that does not depend on the theme.

Comment: look into creating custom themes, for example you can create two themes one dark and one light and then for each one define a color for the divider using @android:color/...

Comment: My question is related to using pre-defined themes, not creating them. There is the following key difference: if I create a theme, I decide all its colors. If I use a pre-defined them like Holo, what's the name of a divider's color for example?

Comment: Put it another way: if I like Gmail app's divider color, how can I access it?

Comment: can't be sure, but looks like either android:color/lighter_gray or android:color/darker_gray https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: It puzzles me how little information there is about this. Does Google not want Android apps to have a unified look?

Comment: Well it's more about how they don't want all apps to look exactly the same, usually I choose a color from that file depending on what I like (usually choose more holo_blue for dividers, but it's preference)

Comment: If you're looking for general theming look here, very useful: http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: It's not very useful to have a theme such as Holo_Light without a predefined "meaning" attached to each of its colors. Maybe Google doesn't want a unified look, but then, what to define a theme for in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity's `onCreate()` method(s), before calling `setContentView()`, set the theme using `this.setTheme(customTheme)`;

or give it a try, [Using Themes in Android Applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own theme attributes and use them in your app's themes, and allow the user to switch between your app's themes.

First, make a file called `attrs.xml` in `/res/values` folder and define some theme attributes:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myDividerColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

Next, make two themes in your `/res/values/styles.xml` (or in `/res/values/themes.xml` if you do your themes and styles separately). One theme extends Android's dark theme and one extends Android's light theme. Add your custom attributes to your themes:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Dark theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme_Dark" parent="@android:Theme.Holo">
        ...
        <item name="myDividerColor">@color/divider_dark</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Light theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        ...
        <item name="myDividerColor">@color/divider_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note that I used `name="myDividerColor"`, *NOT* `android:name="myDividerColor"`

Finally, in your Activity code you can get the color as follows:

```
// the attrs you want
int[] attrs = {R.attr.myDividerColor};
// get attr values for the current theme
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
// first arg is the index of the array, in same order as attrs array above
// second arg is a default value (if not defined or not a resource) 
int dividerColor = a.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this doesn't answer my question. This explains how to use your own themes. What I want is to know how use predefined themes: which colors are used for which widgets in predefined themes